# Center sub menu to ignore its parent's position?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a sub menu that spans 850 width and is centered in my screen.

The sub menu shows when the menu link is hovered.

http://jsfiddle.net/p7tgjLu2/

Here's the html:

```
<nav class="top-links ">
    <ul id=menu>

    <li><a href="#">aaaaaaa</a></a></li>   
     <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">aaaaaaa</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">bbbbbb</div></li> 
    <li><a href="#">aaaaaaa</a></a></li>   
    <li><a href="#">aaaaaaa</a></a></li>   
    </ul> 
    </nav>
```

And Css:

```
.top-links{position:relative; display:block; float:none; margin:40px auto 0 auto; width:850px;}
.top-links ul li{ float:left;position:relative;}
.top-links ul li:hover > ul{display:block;}
.top-links li > a{display:block;padding:10px 0 16px 0;margin:0 20px;font-size:11px;color:#000; }


.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content { display: block;}
.dropdown-content { display: none; position: absolute; background-color: #fff; box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); padding: 12px 16px; z-index: 1; width:850px; left:0; float:left; }
```

The issue is that the starting position of the sub menu is locked by its parent (the link that's hovered).

How can I ignore this? So I can center it?

I can do it by giving each sub menu its own class but is there a easier way?

Comment: fixed would make it follow down the screen (not what I'm wanting), it needs to be absolute but cause it's parent is relative it is ignoring the absolute positioning. @vega

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/pkca97tr/1/

Comment: @vega http://jsfiddle.net/7pas3ez5/ see "fixed" follows down screen I don't want that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to remove `position: relative` rule from `.top-links ul li` and move it to you `ul` element:

```
.top-links ul li{ 
  float: left;
  // position:relative;
}

.top-links > ul {
  position: relative;
}

/* add calculated value to your left rule for dropdown content */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 850px;
  left: calc(50% - 850px / 2 - 16px);
}
```

`absolute` element is positioned relatively to its closest non-static parent. So, in your case it was relative to `il` element which was set to relative.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me if I have multiple sub menus.

Comment: Please update your JSFIDDLE with multiple dropdowns, so I can see mentioned issue, and I will try to help